How to create a typed child table?
This does not work:
create table myid (id serial primary key);
create type mypair as (a int, b int);
create table mypairs of mypair (primary key (id)) inherits (myid);

Is there a workaround?

You can't combine create table x of y with create table x (...) inherits (y). What is your expected result here?

@Schwern My expectation is that the columns get merged.

I think I know what you mean, and I don't think it's possible in PostgreSQL. Could you make it abundantly clear by showing us the resulting table? And do you expect it to still act like a type table (the table to changes if the type changes)? You might get better luck on DBA.SE.
